# How to keep a Python script running to keep reading a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I need to find a way to keep reading a text file by a Python script. This text file should be written by a another software either a Boolean value or anything (doesn't matter). But as soon as the python script recognizes the keyword it should do something run other codes.

I am not able to find a way to keep the python script running. Any suggestions would deeply appreciated. Thank you.

I am using a Windows OS

Comment: What kind of OS are you using ?

Comment: Please mention the code you tried and what problems are you facing? Also mention what research you did

Comment: Are other things also being written to the text file? Or are you merely using the text file as a means of signaling the script?

Comment: see https://github.com/kasun/python-tail it should work for you

Comment: @dejdej I am using windows os

Comment: @Grismar just as a means of signaling to run other codes in python

Comment: No sure I fully understood your problem, but you could use something like https://nssm.cc/download + https://github.com/spawnmarvel/pywinservice to make your script as a windows service and afterwards control the behaviour from a service perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can use while loop to get the line, when it's just added:

```
while True:
    line = current.readline()
    if line:
        yield line
```